# If $A=\sin^{20}\theta +\cos^{48}\theta $ then identify the correct option.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $A=\sin^{20}\theta +\cos^{48}\theta $, then for all values $\theta$
>   a) $A\geq 1$
>   b) $ 0< A\leq 1$
>   c) $1<A< 3$
>   d) None of these

$0 \leq \sin^{20}\theta \leq 1$
$0 \leq \cos^{48}\theta \leq 1 $

So I think it is $d.)$ , but I am confused.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

What about using $$0\leq\sin^{20}(\theta)=\sin^{18}(\theta)\sin^{2}(\theta)\leq\sin^{2}(\theta)$$ $$0\leq\cos^{48}(\theta)=\cos^{46}(\theta)\cos^{2}(\theta)\leq\cos^{2}(\theta)$$ $$0\leq\sin^{20}(\theta)+\cos^{48}(\theta)\leq\sin^{2}(\theta)+\cos^{2}(\theta)=1$$

Comment: Is option $b.)$ correct.

Comment: It seems to be if you look at the most left and most right numbers in the last line I wrote.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Nice method by following the options available. I was thinking of finding the actual range.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. Thank you ! May I confess that I started  thinking the same way (what is the range ?). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $0 \leq \sin^2\theta \leq 1$, $0 \leq \cos^2\theta \leq 1$, and $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You should know that
\begin{align}
0 \leq \sin^{20}\theta \leq \sin^2\theta \leq 1\\
0 \leq \cos^{48}\theta \leq \cos^2\theta \leq 1
\end{align}

So

$$0\leq \sin^{20}\theta + \cos^{48}\theta \leq \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta $$

And the last sum is $1$.